# In python notebook Change the height of a ipywidget

Tags: python, ipywidgets, voila

I am using ipywidgets in jupyterlab for displaying later on with voila.

In order to display information I create several text on containers

```
wd_EXTRA_output = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
with wd_EXTRA_output:
    print('Information will be displayed here... ')
```

I dont want to pass a 'height' at the moment of creating the Output widget.

How can I later on modify the height of that widget?

```
 wd_EXTRA_output(layout={'height': '200px'})
```

Note: I know I could have passed the height at the moment of creating the widget, but for particular reasons I cant do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly change the python attributes of a widget the display will update automatically. So in this case you can do:

```py
wd_EXTRA_output.layout.height = '200px'
```

you can also set the height to other valid html heights, e.g. `'50%'`